# $emit or $broadcast an event from a controller to a directive AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to be able to notify a directive when an event happens to change what the directive displays. I know that directives only run once, so I am wondering how I would go about doing this. I am also not sure if I should use $emit or $broadcast, is a directive a child of the controller?

For example, in my controller I have:

`$rootScope.$emit('PHOTO_UPLOADED', photo);`

And in my directive:

```
.directive('photo', [function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {user: '='},
    replace: true,
    template: '<div id="{{user.id}}"></div>',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      var thumbnail = ($scope.user && $scope.user.image) 
        ? $scope.user.image
        : '/default.png';

      element.css('background-image', 'url(' + thumbnail + ')');

      $rootScope.$on('PHOTO_UPLOADED', function(event, data) {
         thumbnail = data;
      });
    }
  };
}])
```

I tried to do this but nothing happened, the thumbnail was not updated because the directive already ran.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `$broadcast`.  That will broadcast events to child scopes.  Here is an example of using broadcast to send data to a directive from a parent controller:

http://jsfiddle.net/smaye81/q2hbnL5b/6/

Answer (score 7):

In your controller do:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('PHOTO_UPLOADED', photo);
```

and in your directive, catch the broadcast event via

```
  $rootScope.$on('PHOTO_UPLOADED', function(event, data) {
         thumbnail = data;
      });
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to make sure to pass `$rootScope` to your directive so it can be injected:

```
.directive('photo', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
// snip
}]);
```

Modify you code's first line to the above and it should work fine.